# Github actions deploy django application to elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions

I'm simply trying to deploy my django application to elastic beanstalk using github actions but keep getting these error:

```
Warning: Environment update finished, but health is Red and health status is Degraded. Giving it 30 seconds to recover...
Warning: Environment still has health: Red and health status Degraded. Waiting 19 more seconds before failing...
Warning: Environment still has health: Red and health status Degraded. Waiting 8 more seconds before failing...
Error: Deployment failed: Error: Environment still has health Red 30 seconds after update finished!
```

This it the code I'm using below:

```
name: AWS Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test-main-branch

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Generate deployment package
    run: zip -r deploy.zip . -x '*.git*'

  - name: Get timestamp
    uses: gerred/actions/current-time@master
    id: current-time

  - name: Run string replace
    uses: frabert/replace-string-action@master
    id: format-time
    with:
      pattern: '[:\.]+'
      string: "${{ steps.current-time.outputs.time }}"
      replace-with: "-"
      flags: "g"

  - name: Deploy to EB
    uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v20
    with:
      aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      application_name: project-pit
      environment_name: project-pit-cloud
      version_label: 12345
      region: ap-southeast-2
      deployment_package: deploy.zip

  - name: Deployed!
    run: echo App deployed
```

The application is showing up in my s3 bucket but I still get a Degraded health in on my elastic beanstalk.

I should also mention that my s3 bucket is more than one level deep, bucket/project-pit

Comment: The errors indicate that the deployment finished, but the new code failed to run for some reason. You really need to look at the Elastic Beanstalk server logs to see why it is failing.

Comment: It’s weird though, If I use my terminal & do ‘eb deploy’ it works fine.

Comment: If you connect to your EB server via SSH, do you see any error in files /var/log/eb-engine.log or /var/log/cfn-init.log? If so, could you please share the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v20
    with:
      aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      application_name: project-pit
      environment_name: project-pit-cloud
      version_label: 12345
      region: ap-southeast-2
      deployment_package: deploy.zip
      wait_for_environment_recovery: 60
```

`wait_for_environment_recovery` is an environment variable that sets how long to wait for the state of the Elastic Beanstalk instance to recover.

The default value is 30.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be great if you would add some explanation to your answer instead of just posting the code.